# In Flutter does avoiding setState() achieve anything?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-layout

In Flutter does avoiding setState() achieve anything?

I have a StatefulWidget (screen) where I use Widgets that handle their own state completely with the exception of the FAB button.  The Fab button is disabled or enabled when data has changed in order to allow the update of the DB when data has changed. I posted a question on SO as to how to use Provider to handle that and thus prevent the need to setState(), and implemented that with Provider.

When looking at another screen to implement something similar, I wondered if another solution may be better. This screen also contains Widgets that all handle their own state - TextFields with TextEditControllers, so the only place I was calling setState() was to enable or disable the FAB. I had previously created a Stateful Widget to create a CheckBox with its own state because the standard CheckBox doesn't have state. It's fairly simple and only 50 lines of code. So, I did the same with the FAB, I created a Stateful Widget (CustomFab) that encapsulates a FAB. When it needs to be enabled or disabled, it is called to set its own state, and returns a FAB that is either enabled or disabled with the appropriate color. Because I have other similar screens, I can use that same component with them.

Does it achieve anything by avoiding setState() in this situation (for mobile and Web), and if so, which is the best way to handle that (Custom-Widget or Provider or another)?

Comment: According to frequency, If the widget is frequency to be used, make a Custom-Widget, If not make an another choice(Bloc, StreamController, Provider...etc). `setState` could be used in the low complexity page, this also make me realizing this page is easy, take relax. But those are my opinion-based, so I just leave a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 4):

`setState` is merely avoided in Flutter development for two main reasons:

- It rebuilds the **whole** widget, which may hinder performance on consecutive calls if not used correctly.
- using `setState` **only** as a state management couples the business logic to the UI, which may reduce code re-usability and maintainability.

In simple apps, there are no significant issues in using `setState`. However, if you need more control over your code, I suggest going for more complex state management patterns.